# Time complexity of python set operations?

Tags: python, data-structures, set, complexity-theory, big-o

What is the the time complexity of each of python's set operations in [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation?

I am using Python's [set type](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for an operation on a large number of items. I want to know how each operation's performance will be affected by the size of the set. For example, [add](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.add), and the test for membership:

```
myset = set()
myset.add('foo')
'foo' in myset
```

Googling around hasn't turned up any resources, but it seems reasonable that the time complexity for Python's set implementation would have been carefully considered.

If it exists, a link to something like [this](http://redis.io/commands/sadd) would be great. If nothing like this is out there, then perhaps we can work it out?

Extra marks for finding the time complexity of *all* set operations.

Comment: While GWW's link is very informative, you can reason about the time complexity of python's sets by understanding that they are simply special cases of python's dictionary (keys, but no values). So, if you know the time complexity of operations on a hash map, you're pretty much there.

Comment: This link may be useful: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt

Answer (score 162):

According to [Python wiki: Time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), **set** is implemented as a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). So you can expect to lookup/insert/delete in **O(1)** average. Unless your hash table's load factor is too high, then you face collisions and O(n).

P.S. for some reason they claim O(n) for delete operation which looks like a mistype.

P.P.S. This is true for CPython, pypy is a [different story](https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2015/01/faster-more-memory-efficient-and-more.html).

Comment: Set in python also do auto sorting. So do you think inserting new value is still O(1) time complexity

Comment: @thakurinbox could you support your statement with a link?

Comment: Auto "ordering" not sorting.

Comment: @NareshThakur *"Set in python also do auto sorting."* - Not true. You probably just observed a special case.

Comment: A set is most likely to appear to be 'automatically ordered' if it only contains the small positive integers which are pre-allocated when the interpreter starts.  Once you add some negative values or larger ints or other data types, all bets are off.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety That pre-allocation is irrelevant.

Comment: @SergeyRomanovsky What do you mean with too high load factor? The implementation doesn't let the load factor get over 60%, and that doesn't mean many collisions and linear time. What matters is the hash values.

Comment: @KellyBundy I meant for hash tables in general, not specific to Python.

Answer (score 21):

The other answers do not talk about 2 crucial operations on sets: Unions and intersections. In the worst case, union will take O(n+m) whereas intersection will take O(min(x,y)) provided that there are not many element in the sets with the same hash. A list of time complexities of common operations can be found here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Wow, this was a super helpful answer that just sped up my code by several orders of magnitude, thank you!

Answer (score 16):

The operation `in` should be independent from the size of the container, ie. *O(1)* -- given an optimal hash function. This should be *nearly* true for Python strings. Hashing strings is always critical, Python should be clever there and thus you can expect near-optimal results.