# Check parallelism of files using their suffixes

Tags: python, operating-system, filepath, file-extension, suffix

Given a directory of files, e.g.:

```
mydir/
  test1.abc
  set123.abc
  jaja98.abc
  test1.xyz
  set123.xyz
  jaja98.xyz
```

I need to check that for every `.abc` file there is an equivalent `.xyz` file. I could do it like this:

```
>>> filenames = ['test1.abc', 'set123.abc', 'jaja98.abc', 'test1.xyz', 'set123.xyz', 'jaja98.xyz']
>>> suffixes = ('.abc', '.xyz')
>>> assert all( os.path.splitext(_filename)[0]+suffixes[1] in filenames for _filename in filenames if _filename.endswith(suffixes[0]) )
```

The above code should pass the assertion, while something like this would fail:

```
>>> filenames = ['test1.abc', 'set123.abc', 'jaja98.abc', 'test1.xyz', 'set123.xyz']
>>> suffixes = ('.abc', '.xyz')                                                                                 >>> assert all(os.path.splitext(_filename)[0]+suffixes[1] in filenames for _filename in filenames if _filename.endswith(suffixes[0]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

But that's a little too verbose.
Is there a better to do the same checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define helper function that would return `set` of filenames without extension that match to the given suffix. Then you could easily check is files with suffix `.abc` is subset of files with suffix `.xyz`:

```
filenames = ['test1.abc', 'set123.abc', 'jaja98.abc', 'test1.xyz', 'set123.xyz', 'jaja98.xyz']
filenames2 = ['test1.abc', 'set123.abc', 'jaja98.abc', 'test1.xyz', 'set123.xyz']
suffixes = ('.abc', '.xyz')

def filter_ext(names, ext):
    return {n[:-len(ext)] for n in names if n.endswith(ext)}

assert filter_ext(filenames, suffixes[0]) <= filter_ext(filenames, suffixes[1])
assert filter_ext(filenames2, suffixes[0]) <= filter_ext(filenames2, suffixes[1]) # fail
```

Above approach would be more efficient as well since it has **O(n)** time complexity where as the original is **O(n^2)**. Of course if the list is small this doesn't really matter.

Comment: You could improve efficiency even more by using sets which do faster membership checking that a linear search through a list.

Comment: @martineau The example above is using sets. Of course you could convert the whole `filenames` to `set` and do the same thing as in question. It would still be **O(n)** although it might be bit more efficient in practice.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Your statement about the time complexity threw me off. It's better than **O(n)**, it's (nearly) **O(1)** — see [_Time complexity of python set operations?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351459/time-complexity-of-python-set-operations)

Comment: @martineau: Yes, checking if single item is in `set` is **O(1)**. But you still need to iterate over `filenames` so complexity is **O(n)**.