# What is the run time of the set difference function in Python?

Tags: python, set

The question explains it, but what is the time complexity of the set difference operation in Python?

EX:

```
A = set([...])
B = set([...])

print(A.difference(B)) # What is the time complexity of the difference function?
```

My intuition tells me `O(n)` because we can iterate through set A and for each element, see if it's contained in set B in constant time (with a hash function).

Am I right?

(Here is the answer that I came across: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre isn't a set in Python a hashtable with no values?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-set-implemented

Comment: yes, `O(1)` most of the time, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351459/time-complexity-of-python-set-operations can be up to `O(n)` if too many collisions. also the hashing of the elements can be an issue like if they're strings.

Comment: I have not checked the implementation so I won't post this as an answer, but there is no doubt that the time complexity of `A.difference(B)` is `O(cardinality of set A)`, with the caveat of possible hash collisions on certain pathological datasets.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque It should rather be `O(cardinality of iterable B)` because `A` is the one guaranteed to be a set so it should used for the contains-check while `B` is iterated.

Comment: questions about time complexity in Python in general are not easily answerable, python has many implementations, some might have O(1) lookup in a set, some might have set implemented as a sorted list meaning O(log(n)) (and they can still be faster than the O(1) implementations in practice)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

looks that you're right, difference is performed with `O(n)` complexity in the best cases

But keep in mind that in worst cases (maximizing collisions with hashes) it can raise to `O(n**2)` (since lookup worst case is `O(n)`: [How is set() implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-set-implemented), but it seems that you can generally rely on `O(1)`)

As an aside, speed depends on the type of object in the `set`. Integers hash well (roughly as themselves, with probably some modulo), whereas strings need more CPU.

Answer (score 3):

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity suggests that its O(cardinality of set A) in the example you described.

My understanding that its `O(len(A))` and **not** `O(len(B))` because, you only need to check if each element in setA is present in setB. Each lookup in setB is `O(1)`, hence you will be doing `len(A) * O(1)` lookups on setB. Since O(1) is constant, then its `O(len(A))`

Eg:

```
A = {1,2,3,4,5}
B = {3,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}
A-B = {1,2,4}
```

When `A-B` is called, iterate through every element in A (only 5 elements), and check for membership in B. If not found in B, then it will be present in the result.

Note: Of course all this is amortised complexity. In practice, each lookup in setB could be more than `O(1)`.

Comment: My understanding is can be O(min(len(A), len(B)) as we can always find the difference between sets by eliminating elements from the bigger set by iterating on smaller set values.