# Count all pairs with given XOR

Tags: python, xor

Given a list of size N. Find the number of pairs (i, j) such that A[i] XOR A[j] = x, and 1 <= i < j <= N.

Input : list = [3, 6, 8, 10, 15, 50], x = 5

Output : 2

Explanation : (3 ^ 6) = 5 and (10 ^ 15) = 5

This is my code (brute force):

```
import itertools
n=int(input())
pairs=0
l=list(map(int,raw_input().split()))
q=[x for x in l if x%2==0]
p=[y for y in l if y%2!=0]
for a, b in itertools.combinations(q, 2):
    if (a^b!=2) and ((a^b)%2==0) and (a!=b):
        pairs+=1
for a, b in itertools.combinations(p, 2):
    if (a^b!=2) and ((a^b)%2==0) and (a!=b):
        pairs+=1
print pairs
```

how to do this more efficiently in a complexity of O(n) in python?

Comment: @MaharshiRoy You don't need a trie to do this, just a set. I'm not sure you understand what a trie is. Please see my answer below

Comment: If you properly follow the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert), the complexity section lists O(n) time for insertion. In the worst case, hashing fails to provide O(1) if same bucket gets filled continuously. I competitive programming, I have got TLE several times due to this. Trie guarantees O(bit-depth) ~ O(1) insertion. Thus overall O(n)

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351459/time-complexity-of-python-set-operations) @Messersmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that if `A[i]^A[j] == x`, this implies that `A[i]^x == A[j]` and `A[j]^x == A[i]`.

So, an O(n) solution would be to iterate through an associate map (`dict`) where each key is an item from `A` and each value is the respective count of the item. Then, for each item, calculate `A[i]^x`, and see if `A[i]^x` is in the map. If it *is* in the map, this implies that `A[i]^A[j] == x` for *some* `j`. Since we have a map with the count of all items that equal `A[j]`, the total number of pairs will be `num_Ai * num_Aj`. Note that each element will be counted twice since XOR is commutative (i.e. `A[i]^A[j] == A[j]^A[i]`), so we have to divide the final count by 2 since we've double counted each pair.

```
def create_count_map(lst):
    result = {}
    for item in lst:
        if item in result:
            result[item] += 1
        else:
            result[item] = 1
    return result

def get_count(lst, x):
    count_map = create_count_map(lst)
    total_pairs = 0
    for item in count_map:
        xor_res = item ^ x
        if xor_res in count_map:
            total_pairs += count_map[xor_res] * count_map[item]
    return total_pairs // 2

print(get_count([3, 6, 8, 10, 15, 50], 5))
print(get_count([1, 3, 1, 3, 1], 2))
```

outputs

```
2
6
```

as desired.

**Why is this O(n)?**

Converting a `list` to a `dict` s.t. the dict contains the count of each item in the list is O(n) time.

Calculating `item ^ x` is O(1) time, and calculating whether this result is in a `dict` is also O(1) time. `dict` key access is also O(1), and so is multiplication of two elements. We do all this n times, hence O(n) time for the loop.

O(n) + O(n) reduces to O(n) time.

Edited to handle duplicates correctly.

Comment: This solution doesnt work if there are duplicates.
Example: If l=[1,3,1,3,1]  and x=2, the desired output should be 6 but instead it gives 1 as the output.

Comment: Good catch. I think that this *idea* will work for duplicates, but you'll have to modify the `set` to be a `dict` where each item in the `dict` points to how many duplicates there are in the input list. I'll update later if I get a chance

Comment: It will really be helpful if you could update it , thanks

Comment: @MaxDaen Okay, seems like you really wanted the update. Updated! HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: @MaxDaen make sure to upvote if you found this useful!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not giving the correct result for X=0. This code handles that minute error. You can modify it to get answers for other values as well.

```
def calculate(a) :

# Finding the maximum of the array
maximum = max(a)

# Creating frequency array
# With initial value 0
frequency = [0 for x in range(maximum + 1)]

# Traversing through the array 
for i in a :

    # Counting frequency
    frequency[i] += 1

answer = 0

# Traversing through the frequency array
for i in frequency :

    # Calculating answer
    answer = answer + i * (i - 1) // 2

return answer
```