# Comparison of integer against integer or presence in a set or tuple

Tags: python, set, tuples, comparison

I had an issue where I tried to compare a variable of type integer to two other integers using an or, and did not realise that could not be done.

**Original code**

```
model = 4004

if model == 3002 or 3003:
    print("model be 300X")

elif model == 4004 or 4003:
    print("model be 400X")

else:
    print("model type not covered")
```

**Returns**

`300X` #when it should be 400X.

I have two other workarounds, neither of which look pythonic to me, but they work.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Working Code**

```
import itertools

model = 4004

if model in (3002, 3003):
    print("model be 300X")
    cycle_dict = {x: z for x, z in zip(range(1, 1001, 1), itertools.cycle(["C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B"]))}
elif model in (4004, 4003):
    print("model be 400X")
    cycle_dict = {x: z for x, z in zip(range(1, 2001, 1), itertools.cycle(["C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"]))}
else:
    print("model type not covered")


if model == 3002:
    print("this is a 3002")
    cycle_dict = {x: z for x, z in zip(range(1, 1001, 1), itertools.cycle(["C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B"]))}
if model == 3003:
    print("this is a 3003")
    cycle_dict = {x: z for x, z in zip(range(1, 1001, 1), itertools.cycle(["C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B"]))}
if model == 4004:
    print("this is a 4004")
    cycle_dict = {x: z for x, z in zip(range(1, 2001, 1), itertools.cycle(["C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"]))}
if model == 4003:
    print("this is a 4003")
    cycle_dict = {x: z for x, z in zip(range(1, 2001, 1), itertools.cycle(["C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"]))}

print("cycle_dict : ", cycle_dict)
```

**It returns a dictionary**

```
cycle_dict :  {1: 'C', 2: 'C', 3: 'C', 4: 'C', 5: 'A', 6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'A', 9: 'B', 10: 'B', 11: 'B', 12: 'B', ...
```

Comment: What *issue* did you have when you tried to do that? What is wrong with the first approach you showed us? Seems fine to me. What do you visualise a pythonic answer to look like?

Comment: d = {3002: 0, 3003:0, 4004: 1000, 4003: 1000} then zip(range(1, d[model] + 1001, 1). Or you can do f = 1000 if model > 3999 else 0 and  zip(range(1, f + 1001, 1) ( or zip(range(1, (1000 if model > 3999 else 0) + 1001, 1)

Comment: I have added the original way I tried to do it

Comment: hi Reti43, both of my attempts work, they just look clunky (the logic side) and I don't know which method is better, a direct comparison against each possible type or to to check whether a model variant is within a tuple or set., I'm ok with the how the dict is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial attempt doesn't work because `model == 3002 or 3003` is translated as `(model == 3002) or 3003`. The first condition is false, but 3003 is a truthy value. You needed to be explicit with `model == 3002 or model == 3003`.

```
>>> model = 4004
>>> model == 3002 or 3003
3003
>>> bool(model == 3002 or 3003)
True
>>> model == 3002 or model == 3003
False
```

Now, as for which method to use, I prefer

```
model in {a, b}
```

which is faster than a tuple, because the [lookup time complexity is O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351459/time-complexity-of-python-set-operations). This barely matters if you have only a couple of checks, but it's something to keep in mind. Generally though `value in tuple` or `value in set` requires fewer keystrokes to type and its intention is clear.

Depending on your underlying logic, the following may be even better:

```
series = model // 1000
if series == 3:
    pass
elif series == 4:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you Reti, I had not realised model == 3002 or 3003 is translated as (model == 3002) or 3003, great answer and explanation, thank you.