# Why Does Using Hybrid List/Set Comprehension Lower Time Complexity to O(n) Compared to List Comprehension for List Intersection?

Tags: python, set, time-complexity, list-comprehension, big-o

The following two functions both evaluate two arrays to output the intersections of integers in the arrays passed to them. However, the second list comprehension which makes use of a set within the comprehension is said to be O(n) while purely list based comprehension is greater than O(n). As a novice to O notation that hasn't been able to find a good answer, it would great if someone could explain why using a set in the comprehension causes this.

**Purely List Comprehension:**

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2]
    return lst3
```

**List Comprehension Using a Set**

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    temp = set(lst2)
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in temp]
    return lst3
```

Comment: because membership testing in a `set` is **constant time**, whereas membership testing in a `list` is **linear time**. This has nothing to do with the list comprehension per se

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for answering and explaining it isn't to do with the comprehension. What properties of a set allow for their execution with constant time regardless of input size?

Comment: Their implementation does, they are implemented as hash sets (although performance can degrade to linear, theoretically). There is tons of resources on the web for reading about data structures and algorithms.

Comment: @SCQs: See: [Time complexity of python set operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7351459/364696) (which both gives the complexity, and explains in brief how hash tables support this). It's not *guaranteed* `O(1)` membership testing (if literally every value in the `set` hashes to the same "bucket" for a given number of buckets, it's `O(n)`), but if the hash code scheme is designed well and isn't attacked with pathological values, it's typically `O(1)`.

Comment: The O(1) guarantee can't be made because `set` itself doesn't define the hash function used by any particular type of value stored *in* the set. You have to try to get poor performance, though.

Answer (score 0):

`if value in lst2` is O(n) but `if value in temp` is O(1).